# Check if a value exists in a column in mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called accountinfo with a row called username.

When i run the register.php i want to check if the username already exists in the mysql table or not.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: what you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you quickly learn SQL queries :)

```
SELECT * from accountinfo where username = 'something'
```

Answer (score 11):

```
SELECT count(*) AS num_user 
FROM   accountinfo 
WHERE  username = "your_user_name"
```

which will give you a non-zero value if `your_user_name` already exists in the database. If it doesn't exist, then you will get zero.

**P.S.**

If you don't want duplicate username in the database, then you better add uniqueness constraints in your table.

To add uniqueness constraints, use this query -

```
ALTER TABLE accountinfo ADD CONSTRAINTS unique_username UNIQUE (username);
```

Adding this uniqueness constraint will save you from a lot of troubles.

Answer (score 0):

Just query for the username:

```
SELECT `username` FROM `accountinfo` WHERE `username` = :existing_username
-- or
SELECT `username` FROM `accountinfo` WHERE `username` LIKE :existing_username
```